# Group array items by order of their first appearance

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort the items in an array by the order of their first appearance, or in other words "group them together":

```
var a = [510, 510, 402, 402, 510, 64, 510, 73, 73, ...];
```

Output:

```
[510, 510, 510, 510, 402, 64, 73, 73, ...]
```

Keep in mind the order at which numbers appear is important, since the grouped array's order must match to the order that numbers pop up on the first array. For instance 64 happens before 73 and this same order should be applied in the final output.

How to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A somewhat simpler approach:

```js
var list = [510, 510, 402, 402, 510, 64, 510, 73, 73];
var sorted = list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return list.indexOf(a) - list.indexOf(b);
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comments for explanation

```js
var a = [510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 510, 402, 402, 510, 510, 510, 510, 64, 510, 73, 510, 510, 510, 73, 510, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 64, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 64, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 64, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73, 73];
    
    //create array of only unique integers first
    var unique = a.filter(function(item, i, ar){ return ar.indexOf(item) === i; });
    
    console.log(unique);
    
    //conver array of integers to array of object where value represents the frequency of element
    var objUnique=unique.map(function(num){
     var strNum = String(num);
      //initialize object
     var emptyObj={[strNum]:0};
     a.forEach(function(oldNum){
       if(num===oldNum){
         //increment the count for every match
         emptyObj[strNum]=emptyObj[strNum]+1;
        }
      });
      return emptyObj;
    });
    
    console.log(objUnique);
    
    //initialize the final result array
    var resultArray = [];
    
    //iterate over array of objects 
    objUnique.forEach(function(obj){
     //get array of values(count) and pick 1st element [0]
     console.log(Object.values(obj)[0]);
      for(var i=0; i<Object.values(obj)[0]; i++){
       //same logic as above, but for keys
       var num = Number(Object.keys(obj)[0]);
        resultArray.push(num);
      }
    });
    
    //the result for comparison
    console.log("Fınal Result",resultArray);
```